# How would I make my bootstrap carousel fullscreen (height)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, height, carousel

I am working on this website: barebands.com (all code can be viewed there).  I am trying to make the bootstrap carousel span the entire height of the screen (and would autoresize the content based on this).  I looked around at similar questions, and wasn't able to find a solution that worked.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines of CSS so that the carousel picture **and** the carousel container fill the user's entire visible area.

```
.carousel, .item, .active { 
    height:100%;
}

.carousel-inner { 
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Wasn't adding it to the picture, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    function sliderFullScreen(){
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        $('.main-slider').css('height',windowHeight);
        $('.main-slider .item, .main-slider .item.active').css('height',windowHeight);
        $('.main-slider .carousel-inner').css('height',windowHeight);
    }
    sliderFullScreen();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        sliderFullScreen();
    });
});
```

It work's for me :)

I took the height of the window and made the slider height the same, I added it into a function to make it responsive so it recalculates on window re-size.